# Plotly: Animating a variable number of traces in each frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, plotly

I would like to animate a set of frames where each frame may have a different number of traces as also described [here] [1](https://community.plotly.com/t/animating-a-variable-number-of-traces-in-each-frame/46400). I will use the following data frame and library:

```
library(plotly)
df <- data.frame(x = (1:200), a = runif(200), b = runif(200)+1, c = runif(200)-1)
```

If the number of traces for each frame is not always the same, only the number of traces from the first frame will be shown. In the screenshot, the second frame is shown where trace `b` is missing. Similarly in frame 3, traces `b` and `c` are missing.

```
p <- plot_ly(mode = "lines+markers", type ="scatter")
# frame 1 traces
p <- add_trace(p, x = df$x[1:100], y = df$a[1:100], frame = 1, name = "a frame 1")
# frame 2 traces
p <- add_trace(p, x = df$x[1:100], y = df$a[1:100]+1, frame = 2, name = "a frame 2")
p <- add_trace(p, x = df$x[1:150], y = df$b[1:150]+1, frame = 2, name = "b frame 2")
# frame 3 traces
p <- add_trace(p, x = df$x[1:100], y = df$b[1:100]-1, frame = 3, name = "a frame 3")
p <- add_trace(p, x = df$x[1:150], y = df$b[1:150]-2, frame = 3, name = "b frame 3")
p <- add_trace(p, x = df$x[1:200], y = df$c[1:200]-2, frame = 3, name = "c frame 3")
# add layout
p <- layout(p,
         title = "Example not showing traces",
         yaxis = list(title = "y dim"),
         xaxis = list(title = "x dim"))
# and show the plot
p
```

[image: Example where it is not working as expected]

The hacky way I found to avoid this is to add dummy traces to the frames with fewer traces. This ensures that the number of traces for each frame is always the same. By adding the `visibile = F`, the dummy traces are not shown but the correct number of traces is shown. Is the need for dummy traces a bug or am I doing something else wrong?

```
p <- plot_ly(mode = "lines+markers", type ="scatter")
# frame 1 traces
p <- add_trace(p, x = df$x[1:100], y = df$a[1:100], frame = 1, name = "a frame 1", visible = T)
p <- add_trace(p, x = df$x[1:150], y = df$b[1:150], frame = 1, name = "dummy frame 1", visible = F)
p <- add_trace(p, x = df$x[1:200], y = df$c[1:200], frame = 1, name = "dummy frame 2", visible = F)
# frame 2 traces
p <- add_trace(p, x = df$x[1:100], y = df$a[1:100]+1, frame = 2, name = "a frame 2", visible = T)
p <- add_trace(p, x = df$x[1:150], y = df$b[1:150]+1, frame = 2, name = "b frame 2", visible = T)
p <- add_trace(p, x = df$x[1:200], y = df$c[1:200]+1, frame = 2, name = "dummy frame 1", visible = F)
# frame 3 traces
p <- add_trace(p, x = df$x[1:100], y = df$b[1:100]-1, frame = 3, name = "a frame 3", visible = T)
p <- add_trace(p, x = df$x[1:150], y = df$b[1:150]-2, frame = 3, name = "b frame 3", visible = T)
p <- add_trace(p, x = df$x[1:200], y = df$c[1:200]-2, frame = 3, name = "c frame 3", visible = T)
# add layout
p <- layout(p,
         title = "Example using 'visible' attribute hack",
         yaxis = list(title = "y dim"),
         xaxis = list(title = "x dim"))
# add animation options 
p <- animation_opts(p, 1000, easing = "elastic", redraw = TRUE)
# and show plot
p
```

[image: Example of plot with correct trace numbers]

Is there a better way to show different frames when the number of traces varies?

Comment: This limitation is mentioned in the [animation documentation](https://plotly.com/python/animations/#current-animation-limitations-and-caveats) of pythons plotly API: `Animations are designed to work well when each row of input is present across all animation frames, and when categorical values mapped to symbol, color and facet are constant across frames. Animations may be misleading or inconsistent if these constraints are not met.`